# How to know where the unhandled exception occured?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

When I run the app, I keep getting this error:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected
>   range.

I don't know where this error occurs exactly or what is the cause. Isn't it possible to know that from:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

in `App.xaml`?

How can I know where the unhandled exception occurs? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print the message and stack trace. You can get where the exception occured from the stackTrace.

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.Message + "\r\n" + e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);

    }
}
```